# Is the only way to do an attribute comparison in Apache Ranger using Condition Evaluator?

Tags: abac, apache-ranger

I am looking to compare user attributes to resource data to permit access. I.E. permit if user office == office of record.

Is the only way to do this using a Context Enricher with a Condition Evaluator? Or is there something more "out of the box"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, which was months ago, yes, you need to extend Apache Ranger in order to conditional evaluation.